# Confused on the new tray icon and dock in ubuntu 17.10 gnome

Tags: gnome, icons, 17.10

As I understand it, Ubuntu by default uses some sort of fork of this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Bits confusing me:
In Gnome Tweak, the Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu appindicators are shown as "off", despite being on. Is this a bug in Tweak? Or is this because of the special Ubuntu session?

With the defaults, the "appindicators" are tiny, but with the proper appindicator extension, they're slightly bigger and obviously look better. Why is the Ubuntu session giving tiny icons in the tray?

Notes, this question also noticed the small icon issue: [Ubuntu 17.10 small tray icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966383/ubuntu-17-10-small-tray-icons)

This question also notes the extensions show up as disabled on the Ubuntu session, despite obviously being on: [Icon(s) missing from top bar after an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963816/icons-missing-from-top-bar-after-an-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10/964536#964536)

This is not about missing icons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicator icons does not appear after upgrade to ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-does-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: No, this is not about missing icons.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to edit your question and make it more precise including key points like what is happening, what you want to have instead and what you have already tried.

Comment: I asked two very clear questions in the text:

"Is this a bug in Tweak? Or is this because of the special Ubuntu session?" and "Why is the Ubuntu session giving tiny icons in the tray?"

Comment: I guess then answers are pretty simple: 1. yes, it's a bug; 2. because it's a bug ;)

Comment: So no, it is not a duplicate, I was asking two completely unrelated questions to what you marked it as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest an ugly workaround. **Try at your own risk**.

- Remove *Ubuntu appindicators* (**not at all recommended**, it will remove `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage)
  by running

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
  ```
- Install and activate *[KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/)*. It should show most of the app icons excluding *electron based apps* (Skype, Wire etc.), *Thunderbird* with *Firetray* etc. with the correct icon sizes.
- Install and activate *[TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/)* or *[TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/)* for the rest of the app icons.

---

I'm not sure whether installing "KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support" is necessary. But in my case TopIcons Plus is showing only the app icons not supported by  "Ubuntu appindicators" or "KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support".

Comment: I uninstalled both `KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support` and the ubuntu appindicators so now TopIcons handles all my icons (haven't found an app that doesn't show up yet).